# New CEO right after my promotion

Tags: salary, promotion, hours

During September/October 2017 I got suddenly promoted to be the head of IT of a newly founded company. The previous head was the head of IT of the company were everyone was working.

Because they had so many problems working with that guy and that guy indeed said he wanted to give me more responsability, the CEO and founder of the new company "named" me to be head of the IT. Or at least it looked like that.

The point is, I was working so hard and got so much stress during the following months. But no compensation or anything. So I planned to sit with the CEO around January and ask him for a salary revision i.e. rise.

Right before I planned to ask him to meet and discuss it, we were announced the CEO was leaving the company to be replaced by another CEO.

So, I do strongly believe the previous CEO would have risen my salary. I know him since time ago and he is really cool:

- Wants to provide high salaries
- Provides compennsations
- Flexible working times

So, the new CEO:
  - Believes everyone (including me!) is earning too much and won't by any reason increase any salary
  - No compensations
  - No flexible working times any more (we are all pissed off!)

So, for me this has become a big deal. Before I had a given salary with a set of given working conditions. I usually had no stress and enjoyed my job. Now I am fully stress, work so much more, I have inflexible working hours and carry so much responsibility. However, my salary is the same.

I approached the new CEO on that topic but he already made his point.
So what should I do? I am thinking about quitting the job

Comment: Start looking elsewhere, sounds like very poor timing for you. I wouldn't put in a notice until you have found a new job

Comment: And learn to negotiate / get it in writing, next time you agree to something like that. You started doing a "a new job" without it officially being your job. Don't start anything new until you have an agreement in writing. Even if your wonderful CEO were still there & started to pay you now, do you think that he would back-date it?

Comment: @Mawg I think would not pay ne 'back' but forward accordingly what would be fine for me, i.e. only like... 3 months or so not getting the rise.

Comment: @Mawg you are totally right.... I should have got things written. I actually wanted it... but the whole attitude in the company is like "small trust family" so they do not have many formalities. My bad now...

Comment: Let's hope that you learn from experience ... in your next job, which should be soon

Answer (score 7):

You should start looking for another job.

Let's consider the three possible cases:

1. Your new CEO is right and you are being overpaid. In this case, looking for a new job will convince you of this before you burn a bridge.
2. Your new CEO is wrong and you are being underpaid, and will change his mind when presented with new evidence. Since you are underpaid, it should be easy to find someone who will compensate you properly; with another offer in hand, he will pay you more.
3. Your new CEO is wrong and you are being underpaid, and will not change his mind when presented with new evidence. Since you are underpaid, it should be easy to find someone who will compensate you properly; you can then accept this job and all is well. In this case, your current company is about to have problems, and it will be good that you are out.

In all three cases, starting a job search is the first step. Good luck!

Comment: I also believe that. I am looking for it at the moment. I think some opportunities so yes I think he will realise.